# MATLAB show all 'active' plots, plt.show()?

Tags: matlab

```matlab
hold on
ax = gca;
plot(ax, [1 2 3])
hold off

hold on
ax = gca;
plot(ax, [3 2 1])
hold off
```

Python's Matplotlib has `plt.show()` which can be used like

```
plt.plot([1, 2, 3])
plt.show()
plt.plot([3, 2, 1])
plt.show()
```

to display two separate figures. I've tried to recreate this behavior with the top block, with no success. Can it be done?

---

#### Context

I know this can be accomplished with explicit calls to `figure` and `axes`, but the idea is for this to happen *after* we finish plotting, not before we begin. That is, I define convenience plot functions

```matlab
function plot1(varargin)
    % do stuff
end

function plot2(varargin)
    % do stuff
end
```

and each has a keyword argument `show`, which is to be used like

```matlab
plot1(x, show=true)
plot2(x, show=true)
```

so `plot2` should figure out that something's plotted before it without user input.

Comment: `plt.show()` halts the program and waits for the user to close the window. You can write a similar function in MATLAB. Then you’d be able to write code similar to Python’s in MATLAB, with the same behavior. Your use of `hold` is weird. It’s a switch that affects the current axes. If it’s “off”, the axes are cleared by `plot` and similar before outputting their stuff. It’s “off” by default, you don’t need to turn it on before plotting, unless you want to put multiple plots in the same axes.

Comment: If maybe what you want is to set the default figure visibility property to “off”, then write a `show` function that turns the visibility on, and waits for the window to be closed. That gets you even closer to pyplot’s behavior.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yeah I started to find more examples. I use `hold` since the full functions do more stuff that requires it. I added an attempt but unsure if there's caveats and such, does it look reasonable?

Comment: This reads like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), you're describing how you expect Python functions to translate to MATLAB, and in doing so you're using MATLAB functions which do nothing (as described by Cris already). I think it would be clearer if you just described what you were trying to achieve, ignoring Python completely, and why something like just calling `figure` in between calls to `plot` doesn't achieve what you want to create new figures, and showing a [mcve] to illustrate why the `Visible` property isn't working how you'd like

Answer (score 0):

I tested below to work as intended with calls to variants of `plot`, `scatter`, and `image`. Also, as in Python, `show=false` *for the last executed plot* still acts same as `show=true`.

```matlab
plot2([1 2 3], show=1)
plot2([3 2 1])
```

[image]

```matlab
plot2([1 2 3])
plot2([3 2 1])
```

[image]

```matlab
function plot2(x, C)
    arguments
        x;
        C.show = false;
    end
    
    hold on
    fig = gcf();
    ax = gca();
    plot(ax, x);

    maybe_show(fig, ax, C.show)
end

function maybe_show(fig, ax, show_)
    fig.Visible = true;
    if show_
        figure('Visible', 'off')
        hold off
    end
end
```

Comment: I don’t think you need to explicitly create axes, and you don’t need to explicitly set the current figure property, when you create a figure it is automatically the current one. I think that just `fig.Visible=true; if show_, figure('Visible', 'off'); end` would do what you want.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Indeed this works, but the syntax looks strange, why is `'off'` actually on? I've not found `'Visible'` in `figure` docs, is there a full reference?

Comment: You can set the properties of the figure at creation time, see [this syntax](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html#d123e428704). [This is docs for the visible property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html#buiwuyk-1_sep_mw_7bf9e6a7-1c7a-4065-98b1-e283df705a1d).

Comment: I’m not sure why you say “off” is “actually on”? With visible off you should not see the newly created figure. Though maybe the hidden figure doesn’t become the current figure?